# How can I deactivate or downgrade the Yarn package manager using corepack?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg-v2, corepack

Following [Yarn#Installation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) guide to installing the `yarn@3.4.1` package manager using below command:

```bash
corepack prepare yarn@3.4.1 --activate
```

```bash
yarn -v
3.4.1
```

Now, I want to deactivate or downgrade the Yarn to the previous version in the system. The previous version is v1. I didn't find any command or option for [corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#corepack) to do this.

```bash
⚡  corepack -h                  
━━━ Corepack - 0.12.1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

  $ corepack <command>

━━━ General commands ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

  corepack disable [--install-directory #0] ...
    Remove the Corepack shims from the install directory

  corepack enable [--install-directory #0] ...
    Add the Corepack shims to the install directories

  corepack hydrate [--activate] <fileName>
    Import a package manager into the cache

  corepack prepare [--activate] [--all] [--json] [-o,--output] ...
    Generate a package manager archive

You can also print more details about any of these commands by calling them with 
the `-h,--help` flag right after the command name.
```

Answer (score 3):

`corepack prepare yarn@1.22.19 --activate`

downgraded mine from `yarn@3.3.1`

Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: That's because it is using a shim system isn't it? I mean they both still exist on your machine, but only the one activated is being in use. Much like pyenv or nvm.